# How can I extract (values of yes) in vector from ifelse function

Tags: r

I want to extract values of yes in vector only in the ifelse function
for example

```
X=rnorm(6,1,1)
 y<- ifelse(X>0,yes=1,no=2)
 #I get

1 1 2 1 1 1


#Also if I use for loop
  X<-matrix(rcauchy(15*5,0,1),5)


 p<-vector() 
for(i in 1:5){ 
p[i]<- ifelse (shapiro.test(X[i,])$p.value>=0.05,yes=t.test(X[i,], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value, no= wilcox.test(X[i,], mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value)
 p
```

How can I extract (values of yes) from total result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
set.seed(7)
X <- matrix(rcauchy(15*5,0,1),5)
i <- apply(X, 1, \(y) shapiro.test(y)$p.value>=0.05)
apply(X[i,], 1, \(y) t.test(y, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value)
#[1] 0.5011835 0.6214762 0.0983801
```

---

Try.

```
set.seed(42)
X <- rnorm(6)

1[+(X > 0)]
#[1] 1 1 1 1

rep(1, sum(X>0))
#[1] 1 1 1 1
```

To get the values.

```
X[X > 0]
#[1] 0.7212112 0.8666787 1.6359504 0.7157471
```

To get values from another vector.

```
seq_along(X)[X > 0]
#[1] 2 3 4 5
```

Some also use `which`.

```
which(X>0)
#[1] 2 3 4 5

X[which(X>0)]
#[1] 0.7212112 0.8666787 1.6359504 0.7157471
```

Comment: I put this as the example I want the way in order to apply it to a complex example

Comment: What should be done in the *complex example*?

Comment: if I use for loop  for example  p<-vector()
  for(i in 1:5){
    p[i]<- if (shapiro.test(X[i,])$p.value>=0.05) {t.test(X[i,], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value}
    else {wilcox.test(X[i,], mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value}
    
  }
  p

Comment: Maybe you want something like shown in the update?

Answer (score 0):

To keep your `ifelse` statement, then you can use it as an index by setting it equal to 1 to create a boolean vector. Then use `[` to subset from original vector, i.e.

```
X[ifelse(X>0,yes=1,no=2) == 1]
#[1] 1.8418504 1.0860513 2.5771326 0.5809096 1.1458737 1.5731607
```